# How to wrap an object around my data when using Angular $resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, angular-resource

I have a simple angular service that returns a `$resource`. Lets say it looks like this:

```
$resource '/users/:id/:options.json', {id: '@id', options: '@options'},
            create_user: {
                method: 'POST'
            }
```

Now in my controller I use this resource by creating a new instance of my user service:

```
user = new UserService()
                user.name = $scope.user.name
                user.email = $scope.user.email
                user.password = $scope.user.password
                user.password_confirmation = $scope.user.password_confirmation
                user.$create_user()
```

But when the last line is executed, the data is sent but it is not in a object.

Now I have Devise managing my user account and looking into their registration controller, it seems they expect me to send the data in an object called: `sign_up`.

How can I describe in the `$resource`, that I want my data to be encapsulated in my custom object?

EDIT: This is what server gets. It is not happy with it and says that every value is missing.

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"foo", "email"=>"foo@bar.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "registration"=>{"name"=>"foo", "email"=>"foo@bar.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

EDIT2: Working server log with `.erb` registration:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xMEDtMWf72yuTwbkaq21c0ZKynoBSWnSypXfm+xJYvNph1d4iKqLIBwwe0DSA3I/YCU+pAHDd23ylc4y7ximEQ==", "user"=>{"name"=>"lol", "email"=>"lol@lol.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using transformRequest on that route.  Your code would look something like this.

```
$resource('/users/:id/:options.json',
          {id: '@id', options: '@options'},
          {
              create_user: {
                  method: 'POST', 
                  transformRequest: function(data, headers) {
                      return angular.toJson({
                          user: data
                      });
                  }
              }
          });
```

This allows you to change the data being sent.  The data object passed to transformRequest is your User object.  The headers will already have the Content-Type application/json so you don't need to add that here.

Comment: I like this. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var User = $resource(
     '/users/:id/:options.json', {id: '@id', options: '@options'},
     create_user: {
         method: 'POST'
     }
);

User.create_user({user: $scope.user});
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Still the same problem. Also shouldn't the first param in the $resource constructor be for the URL variables?

Comment: So the problem is in the server side not client, what's the server code?

Comment: Made another edit on the original post. As you can see the server expects it to be wrapped inside of a 'user' object.

Comment: Wrap it like this: `User.create_user({user: $scope.user})` (Answer edited)

Comment: This actually works but it seems to cause problems when I have more complicated data that has deep nesting to it because then Angular will have trouble knowing what is what and what goes where. That is why I used the form I showed in my answer. Would you happen to know how to do the same thing in that way also?

Comment: Just change each to `user.user.name = $scope.user.name` don't touch the last one `user.$create_user()`